# How to react date

Tags: reactjs

I have date (format 17-may-2019)column in react-table which needs to be sorted in ascending and descending order.

1. React-table has a column with date and its format is 15-Jun-2019
2. It should be sorted in ascending and descending order on click on sort icon.
3. By default, react-table is not sorting the data with the above date format.

Comment: Which react table you are using? Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: please refer this codepen  https://codepen.io/santosh646/pen/rEwxYE

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an object with the timestamp and label (which is your date). Sorting the time stamps, and updating state which will re-render the table?